# What advantage bolt gives over http and Why should we prefer bolt,

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am developing graph database using neo4j and Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) at the backend. And SDN allows me to connect to neo4j by using either HTTP or BOLT and SDN also provides all the configurations I just need to mentioned include properties and dependencies

```
#Replace http with bolt    
spring:
    data:
        neo4j:
            uri: http://localhost:7474
            username: neo4j
            password: nopassword
```

However, while using HTTP I don't need to include any other dependency in the just `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` works fine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But for using BOLT I need to include one extra dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

So let me break out my question in smaller questions

1. Why should we use the bolt instead of HTTP?
2. How is it different than HTTP?
3. What advantages or disadvantages it have over HTTP?
4. And should I go with it or just HTTP is fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bolt is a binary protocol, more compact, with higher throughput than HTTP. The only reason you might consider using HTTP with the current version of SDN is if you use the HA setup fronted by HAProxy. 
Otherwise, Bolt should be your default choice.

For more on bolt: https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-language-drivers/
https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-bolt-neo4js-upcoming-binary-protocol-p

Comment: Hi @Luanne, thanks your answer it is satisfactory and the blog conversation you have mentioned is also good but I have some persons having some performance problems with the bolt, I have updated the question with links. What do you say about these?

Comment: @NareshJoshi stackoverflow is not the appropriate place for debates. The primary question is answered, please accept it if satisfactory- longer discussions are welcome on the neo4j-slack-users https://neo4j-users-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Luanne I apologize for the confusion, I was just trying put more light on the question anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @StephenC I have done the research and that is why I posted those questions to get more clarity.